# How can I filter list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a,b,c,d......z buttons and each button includes person name according to their name and I have a search input field I want to filter list according to input field value.My codes work for only relevant list I mean when I click 'A' button I can filter only list that inside of 'A' Button but I want to filter all persons's name.
How can I fix this problem?

HTML CODES

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <title>
        Js Filter Search List
    </title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container mt-5">

        <input class="d-flex justify-content-center rounded" type="text" id="the-filter" placeholder="Search For..." />


        <div class="container-fluid button-div ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 mt-2">
                    <button class="back btn btn-primary btn-lg rounded-pill p-3">Back</button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 mt-2">
                    <button class="search btn btn-primary btn-lg rounded-pill p-3" id="button">Search</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-container container mt-1">

            <ul id="myList" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3 ">
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="container mt-4 main-div">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center" id="the list pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">

                    <button type="button" class="btn rounded-pill nav-link active" id="pills-a-button-tab" role="tab"
                        aria-controls="pills-a" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-a"
                        aria-selected="true">A</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn rounded-pill nav-link " id="pills-b-button-tab" role="tab"
                        aria-controls="pills-b" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-b"
                        aria-selected="true">B</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-c-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-c" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-c"
                        aria-selected="true">C</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-d-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-d" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-d"
                        aria-selected="true">D</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-e-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-e" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-e"
                        aria-selected="true">E</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-f-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-f" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-f"
                        aria-selected="true">F</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-g-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-g" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-g"
                        aria-selected="true">G</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-h-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-h" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-h"
                        aria-selected="true">H</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-ı-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-ı" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-ı"
                        aria-selected="true">I</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-j-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-j" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-j"
                        aria-selected="true">J</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-k-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-k" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-k"
                        aria-selected="true">K</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-l-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-l" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-l"
                        aria-selected="true">L</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-m-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-m" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-m"
                        aria-selected="true">M</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-n-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-n" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-n"
                        aria-selected="true">N</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-o-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-o" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-o"
                        aria-selected="true">O</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-p-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-p" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-p"
                        aria-selected="true">P</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-q-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-q" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-q"
                        aria-selected="true">Q</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-r-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-r" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-r"
                        aria-selected="true">R</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-s-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-s" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-s"
                        aria-selected="true">S</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-t-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-t" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-t"
                        aria-selected="true">T</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-u-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-u" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-u"
                        aria-selected="true">U</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-v-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-v" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-v"
                        aria-selected="true">V</button>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-w-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-w" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-w"
                        aria-selected="true">W</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-y-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-y" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-y"
                        aria-selected="true">Y</button>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill nav-link" id="pills-z-button-tab"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-z" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-z"
                        aria-selected="true">Z</button>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content m-4" id="pills-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-a" role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="pills-a-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Adele</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Agne</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Alex</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Alice</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Anderson</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Anna</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-b" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-b-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Bailey</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Benjamin</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Belen</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Bella</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Briana></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Britney</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-c" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-c-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Caitlin</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Cameron</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Carina</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Carmen</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Carol</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Casey</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-d" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-d-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dakota</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Daila</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Daniela</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dasia</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Diana</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dylan</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-e" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-e-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Elaina</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Eden</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Elisa</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Elizabeth</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Ella</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Emely</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-f" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-f-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Faith</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Felica</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Felicity</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Fiona</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Frances</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Frida</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-g" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-g-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Gabriella</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Galilea</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Georgia</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Giana</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Gianna</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Gia</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-h" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-h-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Hadley</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Hailey</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Hana</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Hannah</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Helen</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Hazel</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-ı" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-ı-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Iris</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Isabell</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Ivy</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Itzel</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Iyana</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Izabella</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-j" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-j-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Jacey</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Jackeline</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Jada</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Jade</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Joana</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Jessie</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-k" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-k-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Kacie</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Katie</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Kailey</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Kierra</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Kendal</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Kyra</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-l" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-l-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Laney</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Lena</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Lara</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Leah</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Lisa</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Litzy</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-m" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-m-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Macey</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Maria</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Mia</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Mina</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Monique</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Myra</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-n" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-n-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Natalie</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Nichole</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Nayeli</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Nikki</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Noelle</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Nia</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-o" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-o-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Oceana</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Octavia</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Odessa</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Orchid</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Oprah</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Olwen</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-p" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-p-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Paiga</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Paloma</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Paris</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Perla</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Presley</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Phobe</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-q" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-q-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Qabil</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Quemby</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Quillan</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Qued</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Quinn</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Quadim</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-r" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-r-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Rachel</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Rachelle</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Raegan</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Reanna</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Riley</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Robin</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-s" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-s-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Samara</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Sally</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Saige</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Serena</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Sharon</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Susan</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-t" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-t-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Tanya</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Tara</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Tia</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Tifanny</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Tommy</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Trista</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-u" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-u-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Uberto</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Ugo</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Urho</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Usher</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Uriel</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Udath</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-v" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-v-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Valeria</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Vanessa</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Veronica</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Violet</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Vivian</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Victoria</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-w" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-w-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Wendy</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Whitney</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Willow</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">William</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"> Watson</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"> Wilmer</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-y" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-y-button-tab">
                    <ul id="the-list" class="list-group list-group-hover list-group-striped rounded-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Yadira</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Yasmin</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Yolanda</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Yvette</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Yessenia</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Yadira</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

     

            </div>
    


</body>
<script src="js/search.js" defer></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

CSS CODES

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}


.list-container {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.list-container #myList {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;

}

.list-container #myList li {
  padding: 20px;


}

#the-filter {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;

}

#the-filter:focus {
  background-color: #fff;

}


#the-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.back {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 40%;


}

.container .button-div .search,
.container .button-div .back {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #3D1C99;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  outline-color: none;

}

.container .button-div .search:focus,
.container .button-div .back:focus {

  border: none;
  outline: none;
  outline-color: none;

}


.container .button-div .search:hover {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #4B2BA5;
  border: none;
  outline: none;


}




.container .main-div .btn {
  background-color: none;
  border: 2px solid #4B2BA5;
  margin-right: 3px;
  color: #4B2BA5;
  outline-color: none;


}


ul.list-group.list-group-striped li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul.list-group.list-group-striped li:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: rgb(211, 209, 211);
}

ul.list-group.list-group-hover li:hover {
  background: #4B2BA5;
}

#the-list li {
  padding: 20px;

}

#the-list li:hover {
  color: white;

}


#myList li:hover {
  color: white;

}


#the-list li.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT CODES

```
const input = document.getElementById("the-filter");
const list = document.getElementById('the-list');
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const element = document.querySelector(".main-div");
const li = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item');
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item');

const listDiv = document.querySelector('.list-container');


input.addEventListener('keyup', search);

function search() {
    const inputTrimmedLower = input.value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();


    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

        if (li[i].innerHTML.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(inputTrimmedLower) || li[i].innerHTML.toLocaleUpperCase().includes(inputTrimmedLower)) {
            li[i].style.display = "";

        }
        else {
            li[i].style.display = 'none';

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: Yes I think it will work. thank you so much:)